# Pandas Dataframe replace value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have an input like below, where the column names are repeated in the dataframe..

```
1. Product  Month  lives  paid
2. A        June    123   12
3.          sep    13    13
4.          aug    113   14
5. Product Month  lives  paid
6. B       July    1123   14
7.         July    13     14
8.         Sep     1123   14
9. Product Month  lives  paid
10. C      Mar    12      11
11.        Apr    13      13
```

So I want the first product name A to be copied down until I see a new "product column" name where B starts and so on..

I'm trying something like this, but this one doesn't consider the product word:

```
if data['Product'].isnull().any():
   data['Product'] = data['Product'].replace(np.nan,data['Product'][0])
```

Output required any of the below:

```
1. Product  Month  lives  paid
2. A        June    123   12
3. A         sep    13    13
4. A         aug    113   14
5. Product Month  lives  paid
6. B       July    1123   14
7. B       July    13    14
8. B       Sep     1123  14
9. Product Month  lives  paid
10. C      Mar    12      11
11. C      Apr    13     13
```

OR

```
1. Product  Month  lives  paid
2. A        June    123   12
3. A         sep    13    13
4. A         aug    113   14
5. B       July    1123   14
6. B        July    13    14
7. B        Sep     1123  14
8. C        Mar    12      11
9. C        Apr    13     13
```

Any suggestions that can be made to the code?..

Comment: `df.Product.ffill()`?

Comment: @yatu ohh Yes!, it didn't come to my mind.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So as Yatu answered in the comments:

```
data['Product'] = data['Product'].ffill(axis = 0)
```